# What data type should I use for the mysql column containing null, 0 or 1's?

Tags: mysql, database, null

I want to store `null, 0 or 1` values in a mysql column. There will be no other values for that column. `null` and `0` should be recognised as different values. I'm going to be using either MyISAM or INNODB.

**QUESTION:** What data type should I use for the mysql column?

**EDIT:** A lot of answers, thank you! Just one thing though, if possible people give reasoning for using their datatype over others? Thanks.

Comment: Just curious, and this may shed some light on the question: What do the three values represent? "Yes", "no", and "neither", or are you mapping them to something else?

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. The values are correct, incorrect and unanswered.

Comment: @Madmartigan Do you think that (as suggested below) I should use a different value instead of null?

Comment: I'd be tempted to use `ENUM` or even a separate column for `unanswered`, but with out knowing all the details it's hard to say. If `NULL`s work for you, I guess `TINYINT` would do. Probably makes more sense than arbitrary int mappings like 2 == unanswered. ...but what happens when you need another status? Possible?

Comment: Re the status, I hadn't thought about that before. I'm pretty sure though that I won't require any other status in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `boolean`.

It *actually* get defined as a TINYINT(1), but don't worry about that implementation detail.

Comment: I think this might be what I'm looking for. Is there any particular reason you recommend this as opposed to the other data types people have suggested?

Comment: We would love to use boolean for our applications, but my boss is opposed to the idea because 'it does not work well with Delphi'. Don't know if other programming languages have problems with the datatypes as well... we end up using a simple TINYINT anyway.

Comment: @moomoochoo Yes: It's probably the most basic datatype there is. It's fortunate that mysql implements it as an int, so it gives you the three values you need (and no others).

Comment: `BOOLEAN` and `TINYINT` are synonyms in MySQL. This will not forbid values of 2, 3, 4, ..., 255, inserted in the column.

Comment: @ypercube Not so! You can *try* to insert -5, 2, 3, 4 etc, and it will execute without error, but the value *actually* inserted is `1` for any positive value, `0` otherwise. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38e68/1) for a demo

Comment: @Bohemian: I have tested it. Have you?

Comment: @ypercube Yes, I have tested it and posted an executable script... see it in action [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/38e68/1). btw, sqlfiddle.com rocks to put this kind of discussion to bed :)

Comment: Why the downvote? The answer meets the question's requirements exactly.

Comment: My local installations, both 5.1 and 5.5 give different results than SQLfiddle. Not sure why ...

Comment: @ypercube Smarty pants. I'm going to put this down to "mysql does whatever it damn well pleases, when it pleases, and sensible coding be damned"

Comment: @Bohemian: You never get bored with MySQL, do you? :)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a tinyint(1) for the column type.

However instead of using a null, I would use a 2 or something. Only reason is I've had a lot of trouble doing queries and searching for a null value.

Comment: No, 2 really is not the same is NULL. NULL holds special meaning, has special behaviour...

Comment: @tehlulz I did read somewhere on stackoverflow that people could run into trouble with null values. I'm not sure how much of a problem it is going to be for me. Mostly I will just need to tally values :X

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`BIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/bit-type.html) datatype for this column.

---

If you want to use `TINYINT` and still allow only `0`, `1` values (and `NULL`) in the column (this can be useful if you later want to add more possible values in the list allowed values), you can use InnoDB and a Foreign Key constraint to a reference table with just 2 values:

```
CREATE TABLE Two
( number TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL 
, PRIMARY KEY (number)
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;

INSERT INTO Two(number) 
  VALUES
    (0), (1) ;

CREATE TABLE YourTable
( ...
, thisColumn TINYINT UNSIGNED NULL
, ...

, FOREIGN KEY (thisColumn)        --- this ensures that the column can be only
    REFERENCES Two(number)        --- 0 or 1 or NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB ;
```

Comment: You can, but BIT had a bad reputation (Baron's blog). Is that still the case, or is it considered production ready now?

Comment: @Konerak you wouldn't happen to have a link to the blog?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed everyone knows his blog (and reads it daily ;)). [Here you go](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/11/bit-values-in-mysql/).

Comment: @Konerak: Yes, the comments by the blog author in your link, say that the issue is resolved. But I do not like neither BIT nor NULL columns myself and avoid them.

Answer (score 0):

`ENUM` will be best according to me. That I generally use, works perfect.